# How come this derivative is true?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, finance

I am taking the derivative of forward priced security.

$$
\text{Forward Price} = S\mathrm{e}^{r(T-t)}
$$
Thus, 
$$
\frac{d}{dS}\text{Forward Price} = \mathrm{e}^{r(T-t)}
$$
but I don't get the derivative with respect to $t$ implies  $\frac{d}{dt} \text{Forward Price} = -r\mathrm{e}^{r(T-t)}$

How come we have a negative $r$ in front now?

Comment: You have to multiply by the derivative of $r(T-t)$ with respect to t because of the chain rule.

Comment: I'm still confused. I thought I understood chain rule but I guess not. Could you clarify the steps you took? Wouldn't it be r(1-1) = 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write this out with full details. You are trying to take the derivative with respect to $t$ of a function of the form $ce^{f(t)}$ where $c$ is a constant. In this case, $c=S$ and $f(t)$ is $r(T-t)$. $\dfrac{d}{dt} ce^{f(t)} = c \dfrac{d}{dt} e^{f(t)} = c f'(t) e^{f(t)}$. In this case $f(t)=r(T-t)$, which can be written as $rT-rt$ so $f'(t)=-r$.

Comment: wow that makes so much more sense. I was over thinking it. Last questions then, how come rT drops from the equation? I get why -rt becomes -r... its because t drops, but is T treated as a constant?

Comment: Yes it is because $T$ is treated as constant. The $T$ and $t$ are different. When you're taking the derivative with respect to $t$, you're thinking of $T$ as a constant. Similarly $r$ is also thought of as constant. So $rT$ is a constant. Derivative of a constant is 0. So I skipped a step. It should be that the derivative with respect to $t$ of $rT-rt$ is $0-r$, which is $-r$.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll just add that the reason to keep the other variables constant is that the derivative with respect to a variable tells you how fast the function is changing at that variable is changing. Forward price in this example is affected by several variables like $t$ and $S$. $d/dt$ would tell you how forward price changes when you keep $S$ constant. So, vaguely speaking, it tells you how just the variable $t$ affects forward price. This is useful if you want to know the effect of each variable. Technically speaking the derivatives in this example should be "partial derivatives"...

Answer (score 1):

We have price $P =Se^{r(T-t)}$. Let the term $r(T-t) =\alpha $ for now. We know that the derivative of $e^x $ with respect to  $x $ is also $e^x $. But here $\alpha $ is a function of $t $, so we need to additionally apply the chain rule. Hence, $$\frac {dP}{dt} =\frac {d}{dt}(Se^{r(T-t)}) =Se^{r(T-t)} \times \frac {d}{dt}(r(T-t)) = Se^{r(T-t)}\cdot (-r) $$ Hence, we have got the derivative as required.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Yea that helps a lot! But what is the step from r(T-t) -> -r? How come T-t disappears and r does not?

Comment: The derivative of r (T-t) with respect to t is -r.

Comment: @NikolasGarcia $r(T-t) = rT-rt=-rt+\text{Some constant}\to_{d/dt} -r+0$.